# macOS Catalina change clang sysroot and gxx-include-dir

Tags: macos, clang, macos-catalina

I upgraded to macOS Catalina 10.15 which resulted in some header directory changes.

Now I cannot find a way to change the clang default `sysroot` directory as well as the `gxx-include-dir`.

```
▶ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: is `-isysroot /path/to/my.sdk` not working?